# Update Azure AD App appRoles through MS Graph Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to update AppRoles of my Azure AD app through MS Graph Explorer. The App is for setup SSO with our AWS account.

The URI looks like below. GET query returns all the properties of the Service Principal correctly.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/2141b14a-096a-4f26-a73f-4175a4f475f7

But when trying to "PATCH" the section of "appRoles", I received the error below:

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "One or more properties on the service principal does not match the application object.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "0408c2a3-1f1c-4dd6-aacf-6c2c1cca8b98",
            "date": "2018-08-10T01:13:40"
        }
    }
}
```

The Request Body is as below (The code is slightly modified for masking)

```
{   "appRoles": [
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "AWS Developers",
  "id": "7dfd756e-8c17-4472-b2b7-38c17fc5de79",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "Developers",
  "value": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/developers-SAML-AzureAD,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:saml-provider/AzureAD"
},
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "AWS Admins",
  "id": "7dfd756e-8c27-4412-b1b7-38c17fc1de83",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "AWS-Admins-SAML-AzureAD",
  "value": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/Admins-SAML-AzureAD,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:saml-provider/AzureAD"
},
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "IT MGMT",
  "id": "7dfd756e-8c17-4172-b1b7-38c11fc1de81",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "ITS-MGMT-SAML-AzureAD",
  "value": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/ITMGMT-SAML-AzureAD,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:saml-provider/AzureAD"
},
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "S3 Bucket Admins",
  "id": "7dfd756e-8c17-4412-b1b1-31c17fc1de18",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "AWS-S3-Admins-SAML-AzureAD",
  "value": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/AWS-S3-Admins-SAML-AzureAD,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:saml-provider/AzureAD"
},
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "EC2 Admins",
  "id": "7d1d756e-8c27-4471-12b7-38c17fc5de78",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "AWS-EC2-Admins-SAML-AzureAD",
  "value": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/AWS-EC2Admins-SAML-AzureAD,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:saml-provider/AzureAD"
},
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "Network Admins",
  "id": "1dfd756e-8c27-4472-b2b7-38c11fc5de67",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "AWS-Network-Admins-SAML-AzureAD",
  "value": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/Network-Admins-SAML-AzureAD,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:saml-provider/AzureAD"
},
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "msiam_access",
  "id": "7dfd756e-8c21-1471-b1b7-11c27fc5de5e",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "msiam_access",
  "value": null
}]}
```

I validated the JSON codes but MS Graph Explorer still tells me things are missing.

I tried to run the PATCH query with all properties of the Azure AD App, but received the same error.

Did anyone encounter this before? What is your fix?

Comment: I am able to run with the JSON you have shared and it worked fine for me.   Are you trying to update the Reply URLS as well ?  If so, you may need to update the ReplyURLs in the App object first and then in the Service principal as AAD check if the ReplyURL you are modifying in the SP matches any of the ReplyURLs in the app object.

Comment: did you ever figure out what the cause was for this?

Answer (score 0):

Need to update the AppRoles via `/applications/<objectId>/` rather than `/servicePrincipals/`